# Covariant Flow types generated by Relay mutation vs non-covariant in Queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, relay

I am having some issues with some types generated by the compiler, specifically between a query and a mutation result that eventually result in the same type.
One is sort of like:

```
fragment Foo on MyType {
  createdAt
  hidden
  locked
}

query {
  foo(...) {
     id
     ...Foo
  }
}
```

And that generates covariant properties:

```
export type Foo = {|
  +createdAt: any,
  +hidden: boolean,
  +locked: boolean
|};
```

And in another place I have:

```
mutation doSomething(...) {
  clientMutationId
  foo {
    createdAt
    hidden
    locked
  }
}
```

Which will generate the types:

```
export type DoSomething_foo = {
    createdAt: any
    hidden: boolean
    locked: boolean 
}
```

So when I'd try to match the result `foo` of the mutation and that query fragment calling `commit`, I get the error:

> object type. Covariant property `platform` incompatible with invariant
>   use in

Comment: I already had a similar error, I had to force-cast my variable with the right type because Flow wasn't able to determine which type to choose. Something like `const a = { ... } : MyForceCastType`. I don't know if this can help you

Comment: Great, that works, thanks @soywood, although I am still curious as to why/when Relay generate covariant types versus non-covariant, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to force-cast your variable :

```
const a = { ... } : MyForceCast
```

Sometimes, Flow is not able to choose the right type when you mix them.